# How to reference an object from an array after a hit test in as2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In my game, if an enemy hits a bullet from the array CharShots, then I want the bullet to be removed. Here's my code so far, but I don't know how to reference the bullet that made the hitTest evaluate to true.

```
for (var counter:Number = 0; counter<charShots.length; counter++) {
    if (this.hitTest(_root.charShots[counter])) {
        //remove the bullet
        this.health--;
        if(this.health<=0){
            removeMovieClip(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your bullet is referenced by `_root.charShots[counter]`, so to remove it use `_root.charShots[counter].removeMovieClip();`